# JavaScript method processing fixed by alert()

Tags: javascript, swt

I have SWT application which uses [map service API](http://api4.mapy.cz) (http://mapy.cz particularly) for acquiring image as background for some additional drawings based on that provided map data.

Before the browser component screenshot is made by SWT GC instance, I'm trying to hide the controls from map layer, to have it cleanest as possible. This functionality is provided by service's JS API this way:

```js
function hideControls() {
    var controls = map.getControls();
    for (var i = controls.length; i > 0; i--) {
        map.removeControl(controls[i]);
    }
    //alert('test');
}
```

This **works absolutely flawless in all desktop browsers** by calling `hideControls()` function from console.

But if the method is called by SWT Browser component by

```
browser.evaluate("hideControls();");
```

**it just do not work until the alert() function** (as commented right now) **is uncommented.** Then alert dialog is shown and controls hidden as they should be.

Any idea why `alert()` method call cause correct working of that JavaScript function?

**EDIT**

Some additional code context

```
browser.evaluate("hideControls();");
// ugly ie scroll bar force workaround
// calls JS methods which returns size of map content in browser component
Double mapWidth = (Double) browser.evaluate("return getSizeX();");
Double mapHeight = (Double) browser.evaluate("return getSizeY();");
// creates new canvas
GC gc = new GC(browser);
// do the screenshot
capturedImage = new Image(display, mapWidth.intValue(), mapHeight.intValue());
gc.copyArea(capturedImage, 0, 0);
// cleanout
gc.dispose();
```

JavaScript methods for map size calculation (provided by JS API for map service)

```js
function getSizeX() {
    return map.getSize().x;
}
function getSizeY() {
    return map.getSize().y;
}
```

**EDIT2**

After some deeper debug the method which removes controls from map layer is

```js
SMap.prototype.removeControl = function (a) {
    var b = this.controls.indexOf(a); 
    - 1 != b && ((a = a.getContainer()) && this.controlLayer.removeItem(a), this.controls.splice(b, 1))
};
```

So for instance (for HUD control)

```js
SMap.Layer.HUD.prototype.removeItem = function (a) {
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a)
};
```

That means it directly change the DOM tree, though it's not asynchronous..

Comment: You're probably trying to do the work in relation to some sort of asynchronous operation.

Comment: It's either what Pointy said, or you're doing some time consuming operation after calling `hideControls`, and the browser is waiting until the next tick of the event loop to reflow/repaint (my answer addresses this last scenario).

Comment: Calling `setTimeout` like you show on your edit, with `hideControls()` (note the  `()`)  is wrong. And I deleted my answer suggesting a similar approach, because it was wrong. I checked the map service you mentioned, but I don't speak Czech :(; it's possible that it's asynchronous.

Comment: My edit was wrong, that really does not change a thing.. But without those `()` the `hideControls()` method is not even called.. Documentation for the API does not mention that it is or isn't asynchronous, anyway, if it is, what shall I do with that..? And why that work without problems in normal desktop browsers..?

Comment: We need more info to determine the cause. What does your code do *after* the call to `browser.evaluate("hideControls();");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sean Kinsey hinted it's really problem of browser component, that needs to be stalled until JavaScript thread finishes all necessary steps.

I've found workaround, cause in SWT GUI components have to take care about their event handling themselves, it's though possible to stall the browser until JavaScript finishes.

```
browser.evaluate("hideControls();");
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if(!display.readAndDispatch()); display.sleep();
}
```

It's ugly workaround, but 20 'ticks' for browser to do some trivial DOM manipulation should be enough (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

That `alert` has a visible effect here points in the direction of you having a race condition, where the blocking `alert` call allows the other 'thread' of execution to catch up.

So, you might want to take a look at the order of which your code executes, for instance by using `console.log` throughout to trace.

Comment: Regular desktop browser evaluates `hideControls()` function correctly and SWT Browser component have no console to log into.. Anyway, how to stall the browser and allow him to catch up different way than alert..?

Comment: @Sorceror - what you want to do is add explicit coupling to your code so that it can only execute in an orderly way. This might mean adding flags or hooks in order to coordinate the different code-paths taken.