# SWT browser poor performance with javascript (for both webkit and xulrunner)

Tags: eclipse, webkit, swt, xulrunner

Using the eclipse template for an RCP application with a web browser (SWT Browser), I'm experiencing a very poor performance rendering this page (which uses Javascript):

http://bl.ocks.org/d/4063663/

```
// Instantiate a browser inside an Eclipse View.
Browser browser = new Browser( parent, SWT.WEBKIT ); // or MOZILLA.
browser.setURL( "http://bl.ocks.org/d/4063663/" );
```

My configuration is:

- Eclipse Indigo (Eclipse 3.7, SWT 3.7),
- Ubuntu 10.04 or 12.04, 64bits

I've experimented with both ***libwebkit-1.2*** and ***xulrunner-1.9.2***. Both had a very laggy response, while the same page rendered with Firefox or Chromium responds very quicly.

***EDIT:*** Also tried with Eclipse 4.2 and xulrunner-10. Same behavior.

Do you have any hints (limitation of the SWT Browser, library versions)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but might be sort of related with my problem with `Browser` component.. check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14631967/600132

Comment: You suggest to stall the UI Thread until javascript has finished its operations. However in this case, I'm not making any call to browser.evaluate(). The costly javascript operations are being triggered by direct interaction with the browser ... A possible way to implement your solution would be to fire an event from javascript asking java to stall the UI thread (using the BrowserFunction).

Comment: Browser component from system is always unpredictable.. You may definitely try to implement your workaround, good luck with that, I have no other idea how to improve the JS speed..